# Ruby strftime - show quarter + year

Tags: ruby, date

I'd like to format a date with the quarter and year, e.g.

Q1 2018

Is there any way to do this using strftime or I18n.l? I can't see anything RE quarters in the docs.

I've been doing

```
month = datum.recorded_at.month - 1
quarter = (month / 3) + 1
"Q#{quarter} #{datum.recorded_at.strftime('%y')}"
```

But this is not a good approach because it can't easily be localised (e.g. some of our white label partners might want to format dates differently rather than using quarters)

Comment: you might want to have a look at this gem https://github.com/asanghi/fiscali, it has the option of doing ex `Date.today.financial_quarter`, please note, it's bit dated it seems

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already know how to calculate the quarter, but you're not sure how to organize your code to allow for flexible formatting without hardcoding a particular format that uses quarters.

What you need is for `strftime` to have a "formatting directive" for quarters (e.g. `%q`)

You *could* override `strftime` to add a new directive, but generally it's best to avoid overriding such things.

Instead I'd recommend defining your own formatting module that understands `%q` and piggybacks on `strftime` for everything else:

```
module MyDateFormatter
  def self.format_date(date, format)
    quarter = get_quarter(date)
    date.strftime(format.gsub("%q", "Q#{quarter}"))
  end

  def self.get_quarter(date)
    # Put whatever quarter calculation you want to use here
  end
end
```

Clients who want to use quarters can have a format string that includes your special `%q` directive, whereas clients who don't want quarters can have a format string that doesn't use `%q`.